# Multiple linked angular components to Angular Elements

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-elements

I have around 15 angular components in angular library. Unfortunately I am unable to use that library in non angular application. So I decided to create web components of this library. Is this possible. If yes, how to handle 15components interms of elements